# Multifield widget doesn't show the value stored in JCR

Tags: aem

I am using custommultifield.js for the custom multifields inside my dialog. Here i am facing one issue with dialogfieldset widget. In JCR value of selectgrid is setting properly under node parsys --> gridslider --> options --> item_1 when i submitted the dialog.

But inside item_1 my other properties are not getting store like color1,position1. Below is my dialog.xml. Any Idea how can this will be get store or what will be the exact path to store them. **This issue is coming when i use the items inside dialogfieldset.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="Slider"
    width="{Long}650"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Slider">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <typeconfigs
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="Select Videos"
                        name="./options"
                        xtype="customconfigmultifield">
                        <fieldConfigs jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <gridlayout
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldLabel="Select the grid"
                                itemId="dispotions"
                                layout="hbox"
                                name="selectgrid"
                                type="radio"
                                xtype="selection">
                                <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <grid1
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="grid1"
                                        value="grid1"/>
                                </options>
                            </gridlayout>
                            <fieldset
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                id="fieldset0"
                                title="Optional Video"
                                width="{Long}300"
                                xtype="dialogfieldset">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <colour
                                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                        fieldLabel="Colour"
                                        name="color1"
                                        type="select"
                                        xtype="selection">
                                        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                            <one
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                text="Tangerine"
                                                value="tangerine"/>
                                        </options>
                                    </colour>
                                    <position
                                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                        fieldLabel="Position"
                                        name="position1"
                                        type="select"
                                        xtype="selection">
                                        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                            <one
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                text="Top Left"
                                                value="top_left"/>
                                    </position>                                   
                                </items>
                            </fieldset>                          
                        </fieldConfigs>
                    </typeconfigs>
                </items>
            </tab1>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

My CustomMultifield.js is

```
/**
 * @class CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField
 * @extends CQ.form.CompositeField
 * The CustomConfigMultiField is an editable list of a set of form fields for editing a list of nodes with their properties.
 * Unlike the {@link CQ.form.MultiField}, which works on an array of values (multi-value property in JCR),
 * this widget works on the list of named objects, each containing the same set of properties (nodes with properties in JCR).
 *
 * <p>The naming scheme for the nodes will use a baseName + an automatically incremented number,
 * e.g. "node_1" where the baseName is "node_".
 * Note that if ordering is desired (via {@link #orderable}), it will be managed independently from the numbering, only the used node type must support it.
 * Additionally, a prefix can be given for the final field names (just for the submit field names, eg. to support the often required "./" prefix for the Sling POST).
 *
 * @constructor
 * Creates a new CustomConfigMultiField.
 * @param {Object} config The config object
 */
CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

    /**
     * @cfg {Long} maxLimit
     * The maximum limitation for the items that can be added, default value is 2147483647.
     * Optional.
     */

    /**
     * @cfg {String} prefix
     * A general prefix added to every field name (eg. for "./") for submit.
     * Optional.
     */

    /**
     * @cfg {String} name
     * The container node for the list of managed nodes. If this is set, the individual items to load will be taken from the child nodes
     * of that container node (eg. "container/node_1", "container/node_2"), otherwise from the "current" node, i.e. on the same level as the
     * other fields next to this one (eg. "node_1", "node_2"). In the latter case it is probably desired to set {@link #baseName} and {@link #matchBaseName}
     * to filter out the correct nodes (eg. "baseName_1", "baseName_2").
     * Optional.
     */

    /**
     * @cfg {String} baseName
     * A baseName for the node names of the individual objects, eg. "file_". Will
     * be used to create the names for new nodes. If {@link #matchBaseName} is true,
     * it will also be used to filter out the nodes to load. Defaults to "item_".
     */

    /**
     * @cfg {Boolean} matchBaseName
     * Whether nodes must match the {@link #baseName} when loading the items.
     * If not, all objects/nodes found are loaded. Defaults to true.
     */

    /**
     * @cfg {Array} fieldConfigs
     * An array of configuration options for the fields. Required.
     * <p>Example:
     * <pre><code>
     [{ xtype: "textfield",
                name: "key",
                fieldLabel: "Key"
            },{ xtype: "pathfield",
                name: "value",
                fieldLabel: "Value"
            }]
     </code></pre>
     */

    /**
     * @cfg {Object} itemPanelConfig
     * A config for the panel that holds the fields defined in {@link #fieldConfigs}.
     * Can be used to define the layout further. The "items" object will be overwritten.
     * Defaults to a simple panel with a from layout.
     */


    // private
    path: "",
    bodyPadding: 0,
    // the width of the field
    fieldWidth: 0,


    constructor: function(config) {
        var list = this;

        var items = new Array();

        if (!config.addItemLabel) {
            config.addItemLabel = CQ.I18n.getMessage("Add Item");
        }

        if(!config.readOnly) {
            items.push({
                xtype: "toolbar",
                cls: "cq-multifield-toolbar",
                items: [
                    "->", {
                        xtype: "textbutton",
                        text: config.addItemLabel,
                        style: "padding-right:6px",
                        handler:function() {
                            list.addItem();
                            list.doLayout();
                        }
                    }, {
                        xtype: "button",
                        iconCls: "cq-multifield-add",
                        template: new CQ.Ext.Template('<span><button class="x-btn" type="{0}"></button></span>'),
                        handler: function() {
                            list.addItem();
                            list.doLayout();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        }

        if (config.name) {
            this.hiddenDeleteField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
                "name":config.name + CQ.Sling.DELETE_SUFFIX
            });
            items.push(this.hiddenDeleteField);
        }

        config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, {
            fieldConfigs: [],
            itemPanelConfig: {
                xtype: "panel",
                layout: "form",
                border: false
            },
            orderable: true,
            baseName: "item_",
            matchBaseName: true,
            border: true,
            maxLimit:2147483647,
            items:[{
                xtype: "panel",
                border:false,
                bodyStyle: "padding:4px;",
                items: items
            }]
        });
        CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);

        // typical example: prefix="./", name="items" => "./items/"
        this.fieldNamePrefix = config.prefix || "";
        if (config.name) {
            this.fieldNamePrefix += config.name + "/";
        }
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },


    /**
     * Creates the name for a new field. Must take the baseName and append unique number
     */
    createName: function() {
        for (var i = 1;; i++) {
            var name = this.baseName + i;

            // check if this name has been used
            var item = this.items.find(function(item) {
                return item.name == name;
            });
            if (!item) {
                return name;
            }
        }
        return "";
    },

    /**
     * Adds a new field with the specified value to the list.
     * @param {String} name name of the object to add
     * @param {Object} o The object to add
     */
    addItem: function(name, o) {

        /* new check for limit */
        try{
            if(this.limit!=undefined){
                var limit=this.limit.maxVal;
                if(limit!=0){
                    if((this.items.getCount()-1)>=limit){
                        CQ.Ext.Msg.show({title: 'Limit reached',  msg: 'You are only allowed to add '+limit+' items to this module',icon:CQ.Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,buttons: CQ.Ext.Msg.OK});
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }catch(e){}
        if (this.maxLimit > 0 && this.items.getCount() > this.maxLimit) {
            alert("Items have reached the maximum: "+this.maxLimit);
            return;
        }

        if (!name) {
            // new item to add
            name = this.createName();
        }

        // What to do with values that couldn't be found? we delete the nodes normally...
        var item = this.insert(this.items.getCount()-1, {
            xtype: "customconfigmultifielditem",
            name: name,
            prefix: this.fieldNamePrefix,
            orderable: this.orderable,
            readOnly: this.readOnly,
            fieldConfigs: this.fieldConfigs,
            panelConfig: this.itemPanelConfig
        });

        item.processPath(this.path);
        if (o) {
            item.setValue(o);
        }

        this.doLayout();
    },

    processPath: function(path) {
        this.path = path;
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
    getValue: function() {
        var value = new Array();
        this.items.each(function(item, index) {
            if (item instanceof CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item) {
                value[index] = item.getValue();
                index++;
            }
        }, this);
        return value;
    },

    // private, loads a single object
    processItem: function(name, o) {
        if (typeof o !== "object") {
            return;
        }

        if (this.baseName && this.matchBaseName !== false) {
            // check if o.name starts with the baseName
            if (name.indexOf(this.baseName) !== 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
        this.addItem(name, o);
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#processRecord
    processRecord: function(record, path) {

        if (this.fireEvent('beforeloadcontent', this, record, path) !== false) {

            // remove all existing fields
            this.items.each(function(item) {
                if (item instanceof CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item) {
                    this.remove(item, true);
                }
            }, this);

            if (this.name) {
                var c = record.get(this.name);
                for (var n in c) {
                    var v = record.get(this.getName());
                    this.processItem(n, c[n]);
                }
            } else {
                record.fields.each(function(field) {
                    this.processItem(field.name, record.get(field.name));
                }, this);
            }
            this.doLayout();
            this.fireEvent('loadcontent', this, record, path);
        }
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
    setValue: function(value) {
    },

    // private
    afterRender : function(){
        CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.superclass.afterRender.call(this);
        this.doLayout();
    }

});

CQ.Ext.reg("customconfigmultifield", CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField);


/**
 * @private
 * @class CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
 * @extends CQ.Ext.Panel
 * The CustomConfigMultiField.Item is an item in the {@link CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField}.
 * This class is not intended for direct use.
 * @constructor
 * Creates a new CustomConfigMultiField.Item.
 * @param {Object} config The config object
 */
CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.Ext.Panel, {

    /**
     * @cfg {String} name
     * @member CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
     * Name of this item.
     */
    /**
     * @cfg {String} prefix
     * @member CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
     * Prefix to add to all field names.
     */
    /**
     * @cfg {Boolean} readOnly
     * @member CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
     * If the fields should be read only.
     */
    /**
     * @cfg {Array} fieldConfigs
     * @member CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
     * Array of field configurations.
     */
    /**
     * @cfg {Object} panelConfig
     * @member CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
     * Config for panel holding fields.
     */

    constructor: function(config) {
        var item = this;
        var fields = CQ.Util.copyObject(config.fieldConfigs);
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var f = fields[i];
            f.rawFieldName = f.name;
            f.name = config.prefix + config.name + "/" + f.rawFieldName;
            f.readOnly = config.readOnly;
        }

        config.panelConfig = CQ.Util.copyObject(config.panelConfig);
        console.log("config.panelConfig");
        console.log(config.panelConfig);
        config.panelConfig.items = fields;
        config.panelConfig.cellCls = "cq-multifield-itemct";
        config.panelConfig.border = true;

        var items = new Array();
        items.push(config.panelConfig);

        if(!config.readOnly) {
            if (config.orderable) {
                items.push({
                    xtype: "panel",
                    border: false,
                    width:"100%",
                    items: {
                        xtype: "button",
                        "iconCls": "cq-multifield-up",
                        "template": new CQ.Ext.Template('<span><button class="x-btn" type="{0}"></button></span>'),
                        handler: function(){
                            var parent = item.ownerCt;
                            var index = parent.items.indexOf(item);

                            if (index > 0) {
                                item.reorder(parent.items.itemAt(index - 1));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                items.push({
                    xtype: "panel",
                    width:"100%",
                    border: false,
                    items: {
                        xtype: "button",
                        "iconCls": "cq-multifield-down",
                        "template": new CQ.Ext.Template('<span><button class="x-btn" type="{0}"></button></span>'),
                        handler: function(){
                            var parent = item.ownerCt;
                            var index = parent.items.indexOf(item);
                            // note: there is one last item for the add button, must be ignored
                            if (index < parent.items.getCount() - 2) {
                                parent.items.itemAt(index + 1).reorder(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            items.push({
                xtype: "panel",
                border: false,
                width:"100%",
                items: {
                    xtype: "button",
                    "iconCls": "cq-multifield-remove",
                    "template": new CQ.Ext.Template('<span><button class="x-btn" type="{0}"></button></span>'),
                    handler: function() {
                        item.ownerCt.remove(item);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, {
            "layout": "table",
            "anchor": "100%",
            "bodyCssClass": "cq-multifield-item",
            "border": false,
            "style" : "margin-bottom:-3px",
            "layoutConfig": {
                "columns": 4
            },
            "defaults": {
                "bodyStyle": "padding:5px; border-top-width:0px; border-bottom-width:0px; border-left-width:0px;"
            },
            "items": items
        });
        CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);

        this.fields = new CQ.Ext.util.MixedCollection(false, function(field) {
            return field.rawFieldName;
        });
        this.getFieldPanel().items.each(function(item) {
            if (item.rawFieldName) {
                this.fields.add(item.rawFieldName, item);
            }
        }, this);

        if (config.value) {
            this.setValue(config.value);
        }
    },

    getFieldPanel: function() {
        return this.items.get(0);
    },

    setPanelWidth: function(w) {

        this.getFieldPanel().setWidth(w);
    },

    /**
     * Reorders the item above the specified item.
     * @param item {CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item} The item to reorder above
     * @member CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
     */
    reorder: function(item) {
        var c = this.ownerCt;
        // move this item before the other one in the parent
        c.insert(c.items.indexOf(item), this);
        // must manually move dom element as well
        this.getEl().insertBefore(item.getEl());
        c.doLayout();
    },

    processPath: function(path) {
        this.fields.each(function(f) {
            if (f.processPath) {
                f.processPath(path);
            }
        });
    },

    /**
     * Returns the data value.
     * @return {Object} value The field value
     * @member CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
     */
    getValue: function() {
        var o = {};
        this.fields.each(function(f) {
            o[f.rawFieldName] = f.getValue();
        });
        return o;
    },

    /**
     * Sets a data value into the field and validates it.
     * @param {Object} value The value object to set
     * @member CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item
     */
    setValue: function(value) {
        this.fields.each(function(f) {
            if (value[f.rawFieldName]) {
                f.setValue(value[f.rawFieldName]);
            }
        });
    }
});

CQ.Ext.reg("customconfigmultifielditem", CQ.form.CustomConfigMultiField.Item);
```

I can see my request when I submit the dialog

```
./options/item_1/selectgrid:grid1
color1:red
position1:top_right
```

which should be like ./options/item_1/color1:red for color1 etc. I can't hard code name property as item_counter is generated dynamically by multifield when i add new section.

Thanks

Comment: You might also need to add the implementation for customconfigmultifield along with the details provided, inorder to identify the actual issue.

Comment: I have added the custommultifieldfield.js